# Detect if USB disk is mounted in C application in Linux

Tags: mount, usb, c, real-time

I would like to check if USB disk is mounted in a C application. I know that in a script I can accomplish this via mount | grep /mnt (the mount point where udev mounts the USB drive) but I need to do this in a C application. Earlier I used to accomplish this using system("sh script.sh") but doing this is causing some serious issues as this code runs in a very time critical thread.

Comment: you're not telling what system you're using; on Linux you have all the info you need in the `/proc/self/mountinfo` file, which you can read with fgets/sscanf. see the procfs(5) manpage.

Comment: Sorry. Added that this is required for a Linux application

Comment: then go on and read `/proc/self/mountinfo` -- that's what `findmnt(8)` is doing, too.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280759/linux-function-to-get-mount-points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to check the full list of mount points, use `getmntent(3)` or its thread-safe GNU extension `getmntent_r(3)`.

If you just want to quickly check whether a given directory has a filesystem mounted on it or not, then use one of the functions in the `stat(2)` family. For example, if you want to check if `/mnt` has a filesystem mounted or not, you could do something like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stat mountpoint;
struct stat parent;

/* Get the stat structure of the directory...*/
if stat("/mnt", &mountpoint) == -1) {
    perror("failed to stat mountpoint:");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* ... and its parent. */
if stat("/mnt/..", &parent) == -1) {
    perror("failed to stat parent:");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Compare the st_dev fields in the results: if they are
   equal, then both the directory and its parent belong 
   to the same filesystem, and so the directory is not 
   currently a mount point.
*/
if (mountpoint.st_dev == parent.st_dev) {
    printf("No, there is nothing mounted in that directory.\n");
} else {
    printf("Yes, there is currently a filesystem mounted.\n");
}
```

Comment: I would advise against using `getmnent()` &co. First, they're not able to parse `/proc/self/mountinfo` (which contains info beyond `/etc/mtab`), second, there's no guarantee that the info they're returning is up to date, and third the format of the file is simple enough to be parsed with sscanf (the only complication is translating octal sequences eg. `\012` for newline in paths, but even that could be easily done *in place* with 2 lines of C). It's not worth the trouble to deal with the ornery `getmntent()` interface, ever.

Comment: What else do you suggest to use instead of getmnent()